# SQL Server Management Studio shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut, sql-server-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Team Foundation Server for my DB Project. I'v been using SSMS with VSS and gotten used to all the shortcuts. For example Ctrl + R to hide result of a query. Ctrl + T for output in text format. Also assigning custom shortcuts to system stored procedures such as sp_helptext.

My Question is that, has anyone found or know of a way to use the shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010 in a similar fashion as SQL SMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VS Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard select command from the list, focus on "Press shortcut keys" textbox and set your desired shortcut for any VS command...

Comment: Thanks kzen, but I see that those commands are predefined. How would I setup shortcut to run sp_helptext?

Comment: You'd have to use a macro for that.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010, we can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle the results for query to ON/OFF.

Comment: Wrong understanding of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/vseditor/thread/fab228cf-ef71-4f84-b58d-438f10310f06.